# How to multiply attribute value by 0.20 in any column

Tags: mysql

I have following query. HOw I can multiply price by 0.20 in follwoing query?

```
SELECT e.sku, eav.value AS 'avg margin'
FROM catalog_product_entity e
JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'price'
```

Comment: price isn't a selected column.  Typically you can do (price * 0.20) as modifiedPrice in the select statement

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by price isnt a selected column. I have selected price as avg margin. Can you write the code here which you think is right?

Comment: `eav.value * 0.20 as 'modifiedPrice'`

Comment: right, I wasn't sure that value was the same as price, but you are correct.  See hanky Panky's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment `I have selected price as avg margin.` it looks like `eav.value` is  the field which you want multiplied by `0.2`, You can simply do:

```
SELECT e.sku, (eav.value * 0.2) AS avg_margin
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah that's the one I wanted and I could not figure out how I can multiply eav value.